# match TableA.Id with TableB.Id Than return TableB.Country

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables in my SQLite databaselike this

Table A:

```
    | Id |   Date  | Rate | Person
    |:-- |:-------:| ----:| ------:|
    | 1  | 2022-02 | 6.3  | Alex   |
    | 1  | 2022-05 | 4.2  | John   |
    | 2  | 2022-09 | 2.5  | Alex   |
    | 3  | 2022-01 | 7.8  | David  |
    | 2  | 2022-21 | 9    | William|
```

Table B:

```
    | Id |    City   | Country |
    |:-- |:---------:| -------:|
    | 1  | London    | England |
    | 2  | Paris     | France  |
    | 3  | Washington| USA     |
    | 4  | Berlin    | Germany |
```

I need a query to get Id and Rate of each row, in table A then get Country of that Id in Table B
The result should be something like this
Table C:

```
    | Ids | Countries | Rates |
    |:--- |:---------:| -----:|
    | 1   |  England  |  6.3  |
    | 1   |  England  |  4.2  |
    | 2   |  France   |  2.5  |
    | 3   |  USA      |  7.8  |
    | 2   |  France   |   9   |
```

Comment: Looks like simple join operations, are you stuck somewhere building this query?

Comment: I try to do that, but not work. My searches, not work too. Can you give me an example quarry?

Comment: Take some time to read about joins: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-join/

Answer (score -1):

You need to join `A` and `B` with `Id`, and select some columns:

```
select B.Id as Ids, 
    B.Country as Countries, 
    A.Rate as Rates
From A inner join B on(A.Id = B.Id)
```